# Extra space between top of tableView and bottom of header

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout

I'm just facing a problem that's driving me nuts. I can't understand why there's an extra space added between the top of my tableView and the bottom of the view used as 'tableViewHeader' of my tableView. The view of the header is the view of a pageViewController, where it has its own pageControl at the bottom.

It's weird because iOS doesn't add a space between these items. By default they are always stacked up together without an extra padding. And this space is not from the view of the header, I checked it on the View Debugging of Xcode.

[image]

Screenshot made on View Debugging. You can see how the first cell of the tableView is separated from the header View.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly, but this behavior comes from the `adjust scroll view insets` attribute in storyboard. The view controller has this attribute.

[image]

I think you have to remove the checkmark and your problem is gone.

Comment: I tried that before. And trying to modifying as well the 'edgesForLayout' property. I finally handled it. I post it the answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

After trying to assign the header as part of one of the views that be returned from the 'viewFromHeaderSection' delegate method, it finally worked. But for me it doesn't make sense why I couldn't do the same just assigning the view as 'tableViewHeader'. I wanted to get rid of all the code I needed insert to modify the dataSource and delegate methods of the tableView that handles the numberOfSections, numberOfRows, etc.

Thanks anyway.